# CSS flex-wrap: wrap taking all the space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following widget, with some short info about a product, then the price with a discount and an info icon:

Preview of the widget:

[image: preview of the widget]

This is a simplified version of the widget, to be able to focus on the issue that I have. The issue is that when the price is very long, and the two prices, the discounted one and the previous one, go one below the other (due to the `flex-wrap` property), the container which holds the prices (`.long-text`) takes more space than desired, the info icon going far away from the prices:

Preview of the unwanted behavior:

[image: preview of the unwanted behavior]

How can I fix this? I think it's related to flexbox trying to make space for an element that doesn't have enough space on one line.

Here is the code of the widget:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.description {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.info {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #aaa;
}

.long-text {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.long-text span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="description">Product info</div>
  <a class="info" title="X% discount">i</a>
  <div class="long-text">
    <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">£8,888,888,888,888.88</span>
    <span style="margin-left: 5px; color: green">£8,888,888,888,888.88</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The main problem is that HTML elements cannot detect when their content wraps. This means that once the container size is established (on the initial cascade), the browser doesn't recalculate the size when content wraps. The problem is explained in detail in the duplicate.

Comment: The simplest solution is to put the icon in the same container with the price. https://jsfiddle.net/g1nucy0v/